# Error R10 (Boot timeout) -> Web process failed to bind to $PORT within 60 seconds of launch

Tags: angularjs, node.js, heroku

I read a lot and this problem I figured has got to do with port numbers mostly. Before this error, I was setting my own port locally but after googling a few times I learned that I had to assign the port number that Heroku provided so I went on ahead to add `app.listen(process.env.PORT || 5000);` to my `server.js` but still have problems with ports, I think, according to my heroku logs. I will appreciate some help. Thank you :)

### server.js

```
var express = require('express'),
    app = express();

//app.set('port', (process.env.PORT || 5000));


/* EXPRESS 3.0
app.configure(function () {
    app.use(express.static(__dirname, '/'));
});
*/

// EXPRESS 4.0
var env = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development';
if ('development' == env) {
   // configure stuff here
    app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/'));
}

/*EXPRESS 3.0
app.get('/customers/:id', function(req, res) {
    var customerId = parseInt(req.params.id);
    var data = {};
    for (var i = 0, len = customers.length; i < len; i++) {
        if (customers[i].id === customerId) {
            data = customer[i];
            break;
        }
    }
    res.json(data)
});
*/

//EXPRESS 4.0
app.route('/customers/:id')
    .get(function(req, res) {
    var customerId = parseInt(req.params.id);
    var data = {};
    for (var i = 0, len = customers.length; i < len; i++) {
        if (customers[i].id === customerId) {
            data = customers[i];
            break;
        }
    }
    res.json(data)
    })

/* EXPRESS 3.0
app.get('/customers', function(req, res) {
    res.json(customers);
});
*/

//EXPRESS 4.0
app.route('/customers')
    .get (function(req, res) {
    return res.json(customers);
})

//this was missing!!
app.route('/orders')
    .get(function(req, res) {
      var a = customers;
      return res.json(a.map(function(item) { 
        return item.orders[0];
      }));
})

/*
app.listen(3000);
*/
/***
Heroku dynamically assigns your app a port, so you can't set the port to a fixed number. Heroku adds the port to the env, so you can pull it from there.
*/

app.listen(process.env.PORT || 5000);

console.log('Express listening on port ' + process.env.PORT);


var customers = [
    { 
            id: 1,
            joined: '2005-09-07', 
            name: 'Floyd', 
            city: 'Brooklyn', 
            orderTotal: '43.1299',
            orders: [
              {
                id: 1,
                product: 'Pencils',
                total: 9.9956
              }
            ]

          }, 
          {
            id: 2,
            joined: '2005-09-07', 
            name: 'Jason', 
            city: 'Cleveland', 
            orderTotal: '89.8933',
            orders: [
              {
                id: 1,
                product: 'iPad',
                total: 20.9956
              }
            ]  
          }, 
          {
            id: 3,
            joined: '1999-08-27', 
            name: 'Jade', 
            city: 'Wroclaw', 
            orderTotal: '77.0092',
            orders: [
              {
                id: 1,
                product: 'Pillows',
                total: 12.2311
              }
            ]
          }, 
          {
            id: 4,
            joined: '2015-09-01', 
            name: 'David', 
            city: 'Accra', 
            orderTotal: '13.8465',
            orders: [
              {
                id: 1,
                product: 'Beats Pill',
                total: 11.4782
              }
            ]
          }, 
          {
            id: 5,
            joined: '2001-01-18', 
            name: 'Doyet',
            city: 'Paris',
            orderTotal: '23.9930',
            orders: [
              {
                id: 1,
                product: 'Serek',
                total: 11.4782
              }
            ]
          }];
```

Heroku logs

```
siaw ~/Desktop/angularjshelloworld $ heroku logs
2015-09-04T01:58:16.070031+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 137
2015-09-04T01:58:16.087030+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2015-09-04T03:00:42.864087+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2015-09-04T03:00:45.736332+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `node server.js`
2015-09-04T03:00:48.846167+00:00 app[web.1]: Express listening on port 3000
2015-09-04T03:01:45.855512+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Error R10 (Boot timeout) -> Web process failed to bind to $PORT within 60 seconds of launch
2015-09-04T03:01:45.855512+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping process with SIGKILL
2015-09-04T03:01:46.716529+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2015-09-04T03:01:46.698294+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 137
2015-09-04T04:38:46.544960+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2015-09-04T04:38:48.655956+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `node server.js`
2015-09-04T04:38:50.863631+00:00 app[web.1]: Express listening on port 3000
2015-09-04T04:39:49.016795+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping process with SIGKILL
2015-09-04T04:39:49.016534+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Error R10 (Boot timeout) -> Web process failed to bind to $PORT within 60 seconds of launch
2015-09-04T04:39:49.882153+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 137
2015-09-04T04:39:49.898252+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2015-09-04T07:49:01.371443+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2015-09-04T07:49:03.864654+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `node server.js`
2015-09-04T07:49:05.984160+00:00 app[web.1]: Express listening on port 3000
2015-09-04T07:50:04.146962+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Error R10 (Boot timeout) -> Web process failed to bind to $PORT within 60 seconds of launch
2015-09-04T07:50:04.146962+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping process with SIGKILL
2015-09-04T07:50:04.994997+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2015-09-04T07:50:04.979032+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 137
2015-09-04T10:55:39.200532+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation started
2015-09-04T10:55:39.200553+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation finished
2015-09-04T10:55:39.150765+00:00 heroku[api]: Release v9 created by siawmensah@gmail.com
2015-09-04T10:55:39.150572+00:00 heroku[api]: Deploy b7c65bc by siawmensah@gmail.com
2015-09-04T10:55:39.315718+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2015-09-04T10:55:42.086941+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `node server.js`
2015-09-04T10:55:44.473394+00:00 app[web.1]: Express listening on port 3000
2015-09-04T10:56:42.344180+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Error R10 (Boot timeout) -> Web process failed to bind to $PORT within 60 seconds of launch
2015-09-04T10:56:42.344409+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping process with SIGKILL
2015-09-04T10:56:43.130511+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2015-09-04T10:56:43.131379+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2015-09-04T10:56:43.118411+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 137
2015-09-04T10:56:45.574710+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `node server.js`
2015-09-04T10:56:47.515411+00:00 app[web.1]: Express listening on port 3000
2015-09-04T10:57:46.106655+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Error R10 (Boot timeout) -> Web process failed to bind to $PORT within 60 seconds of launch
2015-09-04T10:57:46.106732+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping process with SIGKILL
2015-09-04T10:57:46.880841+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2015-09-04T10:57:46.864748+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 137
2015-09-04T10:57:48.145151+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=immense-mountain-6684.herokuapp.com request_id=122b26d1-0e5c-4b9e-a887-31cce7531826 fwd="78.88.252.85" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2015-09-04T10:57:49.109952+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=immense-mountain-6684.herokuapp.com request_id=71275557-49c0-45a3-9000-fc7192f9b243 fwd="78.88.252.85" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2015-09-04T10:57:49.534153+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=immense-mountain-6684.herokuapp.com request_id=866e2c82-e4fd-4354-a897-d12fb540bec8 fwd="78.88.252.85" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2015-09-04T11:02:09.401257+00:00 heroku[api]: Release v10 created by siawmensah@gmail.com
2015-09-04T11:02:09.466496+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation started
2015-09-04T11:02:09.466519+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation finished
2015-09-04T11:02:09.399764+00:00 heroku[api]: Deploy be4140a by siawmensah@gmail.com
2015-09-04T11:02:09.801809+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2015-09-04T11:02:12.174299+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `node server.js`
2015-09-04T11:02:15.235379+00:00 app[web.1]: Express listening on port 3000
2015-09-04T11:02:15.946514+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2015-09-04T11:02:18.707201+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=immense-mountain-6684.herokuapp.com request_id=cda497c2-4a89-47bd-a966-1bbc7f0eb89d fwd="78.88.252.85" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=29ms status=404 bytes=211
2015-09-04T11:02:27.101687+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=immense-mountain-6684.herokuapp.com request_id=dc63715a-5797-466e-b36e-28690c9cd860 fwd="78.88.252.85" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=20ms status=404 bytes=211
2015-09-04T11:06:04.494169+00:00 heroku[api]: Deploy 0a02678 by siawmensah@gmail.com
2015-09-04T11:06:04.494288+00:00 heroku[api]: Release v11 created by siawmensah@gmail.com
2015-09-04T11:06:04.554874+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation started
2015-09-04T11:06:04.554885+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation finished
2015-09-04T11:06:04.752759+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to starting
2015-09-04T11:06:06.814554+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `node server.js`
2015-09-04T11:06:07.310814+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping all processes with SIGTERM
2015-09-04T11:06:08.705139+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 143
2015-09-04T11:06:08.757441+00:00 app[web.1]: Express listening on port 3000
2015-09-04T11:06:09.218219+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2015-09-04T11:06:20.708204+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=immense-mountain-6684.herokuapp.com request_id=c8d050c8-ad1a-4721-9231-62c5a39452de fwd="78.88.252.85" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=15ms status=404 bytes=211
2015-09-04T11:11:49.383821+00:00 heroku[api]: Deploy 7d3f718 by siawmensah@gmail.com
2015-09-04T11:11:49.383935+00:00 heroku[api]: Release v12 created by siawmensah@gmail.com
2015-09-04T11:11:49.466101+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation started
2015-09-04T11:11:49.466132+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation finished
2015-09-04T11:11:49.476376+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to starting
2015-09-04T11:11:51.439862+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `node server.js`
2015-09-04T11:11:51.616303+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping all processes with SIGTERM
2015-09-04T11:11:53.001229+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 143
2015-09-04T11:11:53.135287+00:00 app[web.1]: Express listening on port 3000
2015-09-04T11:11:53.680354+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2015-09-04T11:12:01.974355+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=immense-mountain-6684.herokuapp.com request_id=159267f7-a727-4fb1-998c-04e10a1f02e2 fwd="78.88.252.85" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=17ms status=404 bytes=211
2015-09-04T11:15:03.674781+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation started
2015-09-04T11:15:03.674807+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation finished
2015-09-04T11:15:03.619420+00:00 heroku[api]: Deploy c9893f2 by siawmensah@gmail.com
2015-09-04T11:15:03.619545+00:00 heroku[api]: Release v13 created by siawmensah@gmail.com
2015-09-04T11:15:03.750480+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to starting
2015-09-04T11:15:05.413926+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `node server.js`
2015-09-04T11:15:06.551367+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping all processes with SIGTERM
2015-09-04T11:15:07.018219+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2015-09-04T11:15:06.946226+00:00 app[web.1]: Express listening on port 3000
2015-09-04T11:15:08.041342+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 143
2015-09-04T11:15:08.120730+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=immense-mountain-6684.herokuapp.com request_id=59fa1ce4-2d09-4f3b-91fd-fd1e9df50a48 fwd="78.88.252.85" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=16ms status=404 bytes=211
2015-09-04T11:17:43.511952+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=immense-mountain-6684.herokuapp.com request_id=2b1b21f7-184d-4f08-9947-2abb11f71a80 fwd="78.88.252.85" dyno=web.1 connect=2ms service=6ms status=404 bytes=211
2015-09-04T11:18:23.537710+00:00 heroku[api]: Deploy dd0e60c by siawmensah@gmail.com
2015-09-04T11:18:23.537839+00:00 heroku[api]: Release v14 created by siawmensah@gmail.com
2015-09-04T11:18:23.458614+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation started
2015-09-04T11:18:23.458631+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation finished
2015-09-04T11:18:23.648871+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to starting
2015-09-04T11:18:24.884774+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `node server.js`
2015-09-04T11:18:25.985675+00:00 app[web.1]: Express listening on port 41317
2015-09-04T11:18:26.494228+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2015-09-04T11:18:26.646791+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping all processes with SIGTERM
2015-09-04T11:18:28.106828+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 143
2015-09-04T11:20:51.765434+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=immense-mountain-6684.herokuapp.com request_id=8bcd68b1-a0de-4744-b44d-59ead272abda fwd="78.88.252.85" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=11ms status=404 bytes=211
2015-09-04T11:21:03.563517+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=immense-mountain-6684.herokuapp.com request_id=c04834e1-beb9-41ee-9749-cbece8b436ac fwd="78.88.252.85" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=5ms status=404 bytes=211
2015-09-04T11:21:10.366666+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=immense-mountain-6684.herokuapp.com request_id=a9844e0c-7454-4dee-a691-0cbd511cafd3 fwd="78.88.252.85" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=2ms status=404 bytes=211
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it with this:

```
var env = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development';
if ('development' == env) {
   // configure stuff here
    app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/'));   
} else {
    app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/'));
}
```

I know there's a more beautiful way to write this condition, But you get the idea. I'll fix it later. It needed a path to use for the production environment. :)

Answer (score 0):

Problem seems about webdynos not your application. Try to restart it.

Here is the doc about [R10 Boot Timeout Error](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/error-codes#r10-boot-timeout).

> **R10 - Boot timeout**
>
> A web process took longer than 60 seconds to bind to its assigned $PORT. When this happens, the dyno’s process is killed and the dyno is considered crashed. Crashed dynos are restarted according to the dyno manager’s [restart policy](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos#automatic-dyno-restarts).